# SELECT query inside TRY CATCH returns empty result set even when error occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, exception

If you try run following query in MS SQL Server, you will see two result sets as output. I would like to know the reason why SELECT statement still returns result set even when error occurs and how I can remove it when error happens.Because as you may see, I am trying to return another result set with error message.

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --invoke divide by zero error
    SELECT 1 / 0 AS DIVZEROERROR

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRRORMESSAGE;
END CATCH
```

Comment: If you remove the `TRY/CATCH` block you will still get a result set, the same as with the block. Only now the Message-tab takes focus in SSMS.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have an app that uses the first result set, a monitoring app and this is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server streams results to the client. Imagine a 1 billion row query. The results are not buffered but streamed as they become available.

SQL Server started streaming and only then noticed the error because the error happened as part of executing the query plan.

Insert the query results to a temp table and only if no error is caught select the contents of that temp table.

Comment: Is not there a way to control/stop this behaviour "The results are not buffered but streamed as they become available." in SQL Server?

Comment: No, only through buffering yourself using a temp table. The results could be arbitrarily big, like peta-bytes. This is not something that SQL Server automates. (Maybe you should either make your query not crash, or leave the error handling to the application. Why does the proc have to output an error message? The app could just catch the resulting SqlException.)

Answer (score -1):

Please read below article on msdn:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx

It is becasue the try-catch is not inside any stored procedure and it will not go to lower level of execution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?